# Regarding the problem of losing node relationships using minibatch in gcn

Tags: deep-learning, graph-neural-network, mini-batch

When using graph convolutional neural network for training, if the training is done in batches, the relationship between nodes in the adjacency matrix will be lost. How to solve this?

get a good solution
thank you very much!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.